# Derivative of a trace with Hadamard division

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, self-learning

I am trying to solve the derivative:

$$\frac{\partial Tr\,[AX'(X \oslash B)]}{\partial X},$$

where $\oslash$ is the symbol used for the Hadamard division (or element-wise division) and A is a square matrix. I think that the derivative should be:

$$(XA + XA') \oslash B,$$

but I couldn't find a reference to double check it and I recently started doing similar calculations. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)}$$
Properties of the trace give rise to rules for rearranging terms in a Frobenius product, such as
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \cr&= A^T\!:\!B^T \cr
A:BC &= B^TA:C \cr&= AC^T:B \cr
}$$
Also note that the Hadamard product commutes with itself and the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A\odot B &= B\odot A \cr
A:(B\odot C) &= (A\odot C):B \cr&= (B\odot A):C \cr
}$$
Instead of $B$ let's use its Hadamard inverse, and while we're at it, let's define a few other matrices. 
$$\eqalign{
C &= 1\oslash B \cr
Y &= X^TA \cr
Z &= X\odot C = X\oslash B \cr
}$$
to write the cost function. Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= XA^T:X\odot C \cr&= Y:Z \cr
d\phi
 &= Z:dY + Y:dZ \cr
 &= Z:dX\,A^T + Y:dX\odot C \cr
 &= ZA:dX + Y\odot C:dX \cr
 &= (ZA + Y\odot C):dX \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X}
 &= ZA + Y\odot C \cr
 &= (X\oslash B)A + (XA^T)\oslash B \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks. Would you please clarify what do you mean with two colons in a row? (e.g., the right-hand side for $d\phi$)

Comment: @merch Hopefully the introduction of the matrices $(Y, Z)$ have clarified things.

Comment: Thank you, it simplifies it a little. I understand the final result. However, I am still struggling with part of your notation. How do you re-write $Z:dY+Y:dZ$ via the trace operator?

Comment: @merch From the 1st equation above, the Frobenius products correspond to $${Z:dY + Y:dZ = {\rm Tr}(Z^TdY+Y^TdZ)}$$